# What is the best way to write this JQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JQuery, and throughout my code, I quite often have code like this:

```
$($(entry_form_text).children('input')[0]).val(inputData[0]);
```

Or in English, code in which I use a JQuery function, then want to apply a JQuery function on the result, resulting in this slightly ugly code.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you developing an application or designing the application? :/ Who cares how the code looks like when its gonna compile and execute..-_-

Comment: Any other people who might work with the code later - do care.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan and if you try and look back on the code 2 years later - you would care too

Comment: Maybe you actually want `$(entry_form_text).children('input').each(function(i) { this.value = inputData[i]; })`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.eq(0)` instead of `[0]`. It does pretty much the same thing but returns the element wrapped in a jQuery object rather than the native element.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The other answers were great too, but this is more generally applicable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.first()` to get the first element from the element collection instead of getting the first `javascript object` and convert it into `Jquery object` again.

Try,

```
$(entry_form_text).children('input').first().val(inputData[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**:first Selector**](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

```
 $(entry_form_text).children('input:first').val(inputData[0]);
```